# How Perl is able to compile python scripts?

Tags: python, perl

Today I was building a tokenizer for English language in Python and I mistakenly executed the script with Perl. I was surprised to find out that Perl actually compiled this Python code and gave correct results.

So my question is how Perl is able to compile/interpret Python scripts as it should be completely unaware of the python syntax, semantics and all other information required by a compiler/interpreter to compile/interpret a code?

Comment: https://www.perl.com/article/bang-bang/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the first line of your Python script is something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

(a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) line) then Perl will know what to do with it.

This is no different to what `bash` does when it tries to run that file, the shebang line lets it know which *actual* program should be used to run it.

Comment: If that is so, I've `#!/usr/bin/env perl ` in my perl script by Python fails to interpret it. Why in this case `shebang line` doesn't help?

Comment: @BHAT, possibly Python is one of those programs that *doesn't* work with the shebang line.